# How do I tell sudo to write files with a umask of 0022?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, sudo, macports, permissions

I recently upgrading to Snow Leopard. I have noticed that some files written by MacPorts are installed with the wrong permission -- they are written with a umask of 0077. I think I have narrowed down the problem:

1. The `port` command is invoked via `sudo`.
2. My `.bashrc` file specifies a umask of 0077.
3. On older versions of OS X (10.5 and below), sudo used the umask of the *root* user (which was 0022); however, now it uses *my* umask of 0077.

Is there anyway to have `sudo` use the old behavior? Right now, it's kind of annoying because I have to use `sudo` to run simple commands like `port installed`, `port outdated`, etc.

(The problem is described in more detail in this [MacPorts ticket](http://trac.macports.org/ticket/21389).)

### Edit

I discovered the `umask` option for sudo, and in `/etc/sudoers` I added the following line:

```
Defaults umask=0022
```

However, this did not function as desired, because the *real* umask used by `sudo` is the *union* of the user mask with this default mask. In order to override the behaviour of `sudo`'s umask and use the default directly (i.e., not the *union* of the user and default sudo mask), one can add the following:

```
Defaults umask_override
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up adding the following to my `.bashrc` configuration script:

```
# Mimic old behavior of `sudo` on OS X Snow Leopard
sudo() {
    old=$(umask)
    umask 0022
    command sudo "$@"
    umask $old
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion) finally has a version of sudo that supports umask_override. For the record, this works for me:

```
Defaults umask_override
Defaults umask=0022
```

Comment: Can you make this work on a per command basis?  I would like to umask 0022 normally, but then invoke umask 0006 in a single circumstance, but the above ignores that.

Answer (score 3):

how about:

```
sudo22() {
   local UMASK=`umask`;
   umask 22;
   sudo "$@";
   umask $UMASK
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With your .bashrc

```
if [[ $EUID -eq 0 ]]; then
   umask 0022
else
   umask 0077
fi
```

Comment: Good idea! Unfortunately, a little investigation shows that Snow Leopard's `sudo` doesn't actually (re-)source `.bashrc`, but inherits the current setting from the user that invoked sudo.

Comment: You'll have to use the function workaround as listed in the other answer then.

Answer (score 2):

For the record: the current version of sudo as a new option 'umask_override', which should prevent the umask's from being merged, so you should be able to lower the umask, too.
Sadly, Mac OS X 10.6.6 does not seem to sport this version of sudo ...